# Sum of the digits from the binary representation

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, binary, numbers

I'm looking for a javascript function that converts a string to binary and sum it, I also have an example of what I'm looking for.

Suppose I have a string "aB1@aaaaaa", the sum should be 27. I'm totally blank to do this. Please help

Thank you

Comment: I really don't know how to start. Totally stuck

Comment: That's not how SO is supposed to work. Please at least start at making an attempt yourself

Comment: I know but unfortunately I have no idea where to start, I hope you will understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to promote the behaviour of "effortless questions", but it was a simple enough question to answer:

```
const strBinSum = (str) => str
  .split('') // split the string into individual characters
  .map(s => 
    s.charCodeAt(0).toString(2) // map them to their binary representation
   )
  .join('') // join the resulting array
  .split('') // split it again
  .filter(x => x === '1') // return only 1s
  .length; // therefore summing it by returning the amount of 1s.

  strBinSum('aB1@aaaaaa'); // 27
```

Comment: @NeerajSharma no worries, but do read up on what CertainPerformance mentioned, [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).